# TidyHtml not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am using TidyHtml to clean up html files in my application in a Linux envorment. I do realize that that libtidy is a C library.  I did include it in the extern "C"{} syntax as indicated in my code. This is the example from the TidyHtml website adapted by me to use in a C++ example and I added the printf() function in conditions.

There are two problems. The first starting with `tidyOptSetBool()` which fails and the `printf("%s\n", "1");` line is never reached.  The second is

```
tidyBufFree( &output );
tidyBufFree( &errbuf );
```

lines cause a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

This is the full code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tidy.h>
#include <tidybuffio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    int tidyHtml(){
        const char* input = "<title>Foo</title><p>Foo!";
        TidyBuffer output = {0};
        TidyBuffer errbuf = {0};
        int rc = -1;
        Bool ok;

        TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate();                     // Initialize "document"
        printf( "Tidying:\t%s\n", input );

        ok = tidyOptSetBool( tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes );  // Convert to XHTML
        if ( ok ){
            rc = tidySetErrorBuffer( tdoc, &errbuf );      // Capture diagnostics
            printf("%s\n", "1");
        }

        if ( rc >= 0 ){
        rc = tidyParseString( tdoc, input );           // Parse the input
            printf("%s\n", "2");
        }
        if ( rc >= 0 ){
        rc = tidyCleanAndRepair( tdoc );               // Tidy it up!
            printf("%s\n", "3");
        }
        if ( rc >= 0 ){
        rc = tidyRunDiagnostics( tdoc );               // Kvetch
            printf("%s\n", "4");
        }
        if ( rc > 1 ){                                    // If error, force output.
        rc = ( tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyForceOutput, yes) ? rc : -1 );
            printf("%s\n", "5");
        }
        if ( rc >= 0 ){
        rc = tidySaveBuffer( tdoc, &output );          // Pretty Print
            printf("%s\n", "6");
        }

        if ( rc >= 0 )
        {
        if ( rc > 0 )
          printf( "\nDiagnostics:\n\n%s", errbuf.bp );
        printf( "\nAnd here is the result:\n\n%s", output.bp );
        }
        else
        printf( "A severe error (%d) occurred.\n", rc );

        tidyBufFree( &output );
        tidyBufFree( &errbuf );
        tidyRelease( tdoc );
        return rc;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    tidyHtml();
}
```

Here is my complie statement `g++ -o main main2.cpp -ltidy` which reports 0 errors.

and this is output when the application is run:

```
Tidying:    <title>Foo</title><p>Foo!
A severe error (-1) occurred.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why `tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes);` is returning `no`.  Wrapping that routine in `extern "C"` probably is not doing what you think it ought to.  The tidyBufFree SEGV is probably because `tidyBufInit(&output);` has not been done.  You may want to write your own C routine that interfaces with Tidy, and then call your C routine from your C++ code.

Comment: My copy of tidy has the `extern "C"` specifies in the header file. They wouldn't help around the call site anyway. Does the code work when you compile it in C mode?

Comment: I tried compiling it in C `gcc -o main main2.cpp -ltidy ` and still get the same result. I also tried the same command but this time removed the extern "C". That also gives me the same result.